# How do I apply a style to all children of an element

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have an element with `class='myTestClass'`. How do I apply a css style to all children of this elements? I only want to apply the style to the elements children. Not its grand children.

I could use

```
.myTestClass > div {
  margin: 0 20px;
}
```

which work for all `div` children, but I would like a solution which works for all children. I thought I could use `*`, but

```
.myTestClass > * {
  margin: 0 20px;
}
```

does not work.

Edit

The `.myTestClass > *` selector does not apply the rule in firefox 26, and there is no other rule for margin according to firebug. And it works if I replace `*` with `div`.

Comment: How does it 'not work'? Bear in mind that descendants of those child elements will (likely) inherit most of the styles assigned to  those child elements.

Comment: Debug this with the inspector and see if there is a rule taking it over

Answer (score 260, accepted):

As commented by [David Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26349987/how-do-i-apply-a-style-to-all-children-of-an-elements#comment41360515_26349987), descendants of those child elements will (likely) inherit most of the styles assigned to those child elements.

You need to wrap your `.myTestClass` inside an element and apply the styles to descendants by adding `.wrapper *` [descendant selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_selectors). Then, add `.myTestClass > *` [child selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors) to apply the style to the elements children, not its grand children. For example like this:

**JSFiddle - [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/a8wmyg39/)**

```css
.wrapper * {
    color: blue;
    margin: 0 100px; /* Only for demo */
}
.myTestClass > * {
    color:red;
    margin: 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="myTestClass">Text 0
        <div>Text 1</div>
        <span>Text 1</span>
        <div>Text 1
            <p>Text 2</p>
            <div>Text 2</div>
        </div>
        <p>Text 1</p>
    </div>
    <div>Text 0</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Never use a universal selector. It has a big performance impact on rendering.

Comment: @yesIcan: Ok that is good to know....do you have an alternate solution that doesn't use the universal selector?

Comment: The performance of the universal selector isn't that bad on modern browsers. [Here's a reference](http://www.telerik.com/blogs/css-tip-star-selector-not-that-bad). My own experience at work corroborates this author's conclusion.

Comment: Use universal selectors whenever you want, and if the performance is acceptable for your situation, then there's no need to find an alternative.

Answer (score -2):

Instead of the `*` selector you can use the `:not(selector)` with the `>` selector and set something that definitely wont be a child.

Edit: I thought it would be faster but it turns out I was wrong. Disregard.

Example:

```html
.container > :not(marquee){
        color:red;
    }


<div class="container">
    <p></p>
    <span></span>
<div>
```

Comment: What's the advantage of doing this?

Comment: @WilsonBiggs - it appears to be a misguided attempt to "not use a universal selector". But its obviously a bad idea, as it is "near-universal", yet requires an additional test - So it has to do all the work that a universal selector would, and then do additional work.

Comment: :not(selector) only works on safari and it doesn't seems it will work on chrome / firefox