# How can select all child elements by class or id using css?

Tags: html, css

I want to add specific style property on all child elements of this `.feature-section-heading` class. I know i can do that using below trick

```
.feature-section-heading > h1 {...}
```

But above logic will implement on just `h1` tag. So is there possible that i can add style property on all child elements? I searched about that and find accepted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4910077/select-all-child-elements-recursively-in-css), but it does not work.

Comment: `.feature-section-heading > * {...}`  would apply the style to all immediate children (but there may be a better way to achieve what you are trying to do).  The universal selector, `*` is not considered efficient css.  What is it that you are trying to apply?

Comment: this was asked previously

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26349987/how-do-i-apply-a-style-to-all-children-of-an-elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [universal selector](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#universal-selector) instead of a [type selector](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#type-selectors).

```
.feature-section-heading > *
```

Answer (score 2):

**CSS**

```
.feature-section-heading > * {...}
```

You can use the `*` as all element selector.

Answer (score 1):

You Can use * (Asterik Selector)

Here is the [**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/2ooyh6ah/)

CSS

```
.foo *{background:red}
```

HTML

```
<div class="foo">

<span>1</span>
<p>2</p>
<div>3</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Access All childrens with [Css * selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_all.asp) as in code snippet below:

```
.feature-section-heading > * {
    background: red;
}
```

Comment: That matches all descendants, not just children.

Answer (score 0):

Please find the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lvng1tas/) link that illustrates the desired behavior.

**HTML**

```
<div class="feature-section-heading">
    I am parent div
    <br />
    <h1>
        Heading
    </h1>
    <div>
        Child DIV
    </div>
    <div>
        Child DIV
    </div>
    <p>
        Child paragraph
    </p>
    <p>
        Child paragraph
    </p>
    <p>
        Child paragraph
    </p>
    <span>
        Child span
    </span>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.feature-section-heading {
  color: red;
}
.feature-section-heading > :not(:empty){
    color: darkgreen;
}
```