# How to select all anchor tags that are children of the nav tag?

Tags: html, css

The CSS rules aren't being applied to the html document.

```css
nav > a {
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Store</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

The expectation is that the color would be white, it isn't it nothing changes.

Comment: `>` means direct child - try without it `nav a`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I apply a style to all children of an element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26349987/how-do-i-apply-a-style-to-all-children-of-an-element)

Answer (score 5):

The `>` means "direct child" and in your case it's not a direct child. You can use `nav a` which means "every a in nav"

```css
nav a {
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Store</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
nav > ul > li > a {
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with the `>`, do this in your css instead:

```
nav a {
    color: #ffffff;
}
```