# How to use a single CSS parent class for styling grandchildren elements?

Tags: html, css

Given the following snippet, how can I use the `parent` class for styling the grandchild element?

```html
<body>
  <div class='parent'>
    <ul>
      <li>grandchild</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: What is the expected result? This is unclear to me and may be good to know to answer the question. When reading your question I was thinking about [nth](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-of-type.asp) but this is also a [selector](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_selectors.asp).

Comment: Use `.wrapper * { display: inline; }` for the _"Apply to all part"_

Comment: Your code already does what your question is asking.

Comment: `.wrapper ul > li {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0;   
}` This could work, but it uses selectors.

Comment: @hamza765 not necessarily, I would like the wrapper class to display inline for all child elements. If that was true, all child elements would be displayed horizontally

Comment: check this out then: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26349987/how-do-i-apply-a-style-to-all-children-of-an-element

Answer (score 1):

```
.wrapper * {
    display: inline; 
}
```

So what `.wrapper *` is telling is us to select any selector (`*` being the wildcard) that's nested in the `.wrapper` class.

If you want to recursively select `ul` elements inside of the `.wrapper`, you can just use what you already have. However, if you want only `ul` elements that are direct children of the `div`, you can use the `.wrapper > ul` selector.

Comment: what if I wanted to select `li` elements inside the ul?

Comment: @kevinjaypatel `ul > li`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `.wrapper *:first-child` to get the first element nestled inside the parent element.